# Html page doesn't display the content

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

I am building a website and this is my HTML code of my index.html page.

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Watch on</td>
            <td>Youtube</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Channel</td>
            <td>jonathanlootens</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>video title</td>
            <dt>Mickey en de stomende drol</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>link</td>
            <td>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

[image]

See the snippet code.

When I open the index.html page in my web browser application, I only see a white page, nothing at all. When I open the internet explorer with devtools I don't see any error.

Comment: Content lives inside `<body></body>` - You should look at some introductory examples

Comment: O I see, strange that internet explorer doesn't display anything from mistakes

Comment: [See this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp)

Comment: I would not recommend w3schools, instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/HTML/Write_a_simple_page_in_HTML

Comment: If you put your HTML into the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) it will tell you if it's valid or not

Comment: @AlexK. Why ? The explanation is perfect or should we post only official references in SO ?

Comment: Please upvote my answer , you had misspelt td tag

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your content inside of

```
<body></body>
```

tags and see if that helps.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Watch on</td>
                <td>Youtube</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Channel</td>
                <td>jonathanlootens</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>video title</td>
                <td>Mickey en de stomende drol</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>link</td>
                <td>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good link for you to get started [HTML Table CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/).

Anyway, there's a lot wrong with your code sample.

1. There's no `<!DOCTYPE>`
2. You don't have a `<body>`
3. You don't have table headers `<thead>` nor `<th>`
4. You don't have a table body `<tbody>`

Comment: 1) doctype is a very very good thing but it is not _mandatory_. 2) right. 3) it's not required at all. 4) it's not required. So answer is finally just _"put it inside body tag"_.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti To answer the immediate question, yes. As far as giving someone overall general HTML knowledge, I think it's irresponsible to only tell them they are missing the `<body>` tag. I hope you inherit this guy's code and have to deal with it if you think we should provide as little knowledge as possible

Comment: I agree about 1) but points 3) and 4) are just wrong. To have or not `<tbody>` and `<thead>` (or even just `<th>`) is completely unrelated to his question and it's not invalid or strange HTML (I would say it's **perfectly valid and even good**). In case you're suggesting to _always_ use `<tbody>` (and `<thead>` and `<th>`) then you may also explain reasoning for that (they're not optional closing tags which may be omitted but you'll make _code_ less readable).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add any code, there is syntax mistake 
            `<dt>Mickey en de stomende drol</td>` 
The `</td>` doesn't have a valid `<td>`
You have misspelt tag name

Answer (score 1):

There are many mistakes, however the absence of the  tags are whats stopping your content from displaying.
Try:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Watch on</td>
            <td>Youtube</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Channel</td>
            <td>jonathanlootens</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>video title</td>
            <td>Mickey en de stomende drol</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>link</td>
            <td>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3leCIk2eyQ</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I would recommend looking at Code Academy (http://www.codecademy.com/) in order to develop your skills.It's a great free site that provides tutorials and teaches the basics of web development.